# Clarification on proof about minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

In Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, Chapter 8C, there is a proof that states:

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $q \in \mathcal{P}(F)$. Then $q(T) = 0$ if and only if $q$ is a polynomial of $T$.

When proving the other direction, Axler uses the Division Algorithm for Polynomials, $q = ps + r$ and deg $r$ < deg $p$. Assuming that $q(T) = 0$, he gets the equation $0 = q(T) = p(T)s(T) + r(T) = r(T)$.

My question it, how does $p(T)s(T) + r(T) = r(T)$ in this case? I understand that $p$ has a higher coefficient than $r$, but how does $p(T)s(T)$ just become $0$ here?

Comment: Do you mean $p(T)=0$ ?

Comment: It may be the case here that $p(T) = 0$ hence $p(T)s(T) + r(T) = r(T)$, but I am just confused about how this equality ($p(T)s(T) + r(T) = r(T)$) is derived.

Comment: Ah ok I realized I missed a line at the start of the proof defining $p(T)$ as the minimal polynomial of $T$, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $p$ is the minimal polynmial of $T$. In particular, $p(T)=0$.

Comment: Ah ok I realized I missed a line at the start of the proof defining $p(T)$ as the minimal polynomial of $T$, it makes sense now.